# How do I make my function as asynchronous in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, async-await

I am trying to understand the async behaviour of Javascript, how can we implement in normal functions. For example below code I am trying to implement a custom SetTimeout function which would work asynchronously. It should call the function `muCsutSetInterval` and go the `console.log("after");`.

Please suggest the right way to do it. Appreciate your help..

```
var myCustSetInterval = function (time, callback){
    let initial = new Date();
    let current;
    while(true){
        current = new Date();
        if(current.getTime()-initial.getTime()===time){
            break;
        }
    }
    callback();
}

console.log("before");

myCustSetInterval(5000,()=>{
    console.log("Callback");
});

console.log("after");
```

Comment: You cant. Use `setTimeout` !

Comment: javascript is synchronous. To get asynchronous results, you have to rely on [apis](https://nodejs.org/api/index.html) that aren't bound by that rule.

Comment: @Igor - I'm probably wrong, but I don't think that is what the OP is asking. I believe the OP is interested in understanding the use of Async/Await along with Promise objects.

Comment: @RandyCasburn - maybe. I do not see any reference to either keyword async/await in the question though.

Comment: Right - was going by the tags

Answer (score 1):

You cant write asynchronous javascript. However the javascript API provides internal functions (`setTimeout`, `fetch`) that behave asynchronously, which you can work with. So you need those async internal calls to actually write async code. E.g.:

```
function customSetTimeout(callback, ms, ...args) {
  const ends = Date.now() + ms;
  (function check() {
     if(new Date >= ends) {
       callback(...args);
     } else {
       setTimeout(check, 0); // <- the internal call
     }
  })()
}
```

Comment: Why are people downvoting this? Perfectly valid answer.